# How to update from OpenSSL 1.1.1 to OpenSSL 3.0.9?

Tags: 20.04, openssl

I've just noticed that there's a recent OpenSSL vulnerability.

```
An OpenSSL vulnerability has recently been fixed with USN-6188-1 & 6119-1:
CVE-2023-2650: possible DoS translating ASN.1 object identifiers.
Ensure you have updated the package to its latest version.
```

What are the correct steps to update from version 1.1.1 to version 3.0.9? I am specially interested in the configuration phase of OpenSSL 3.

This is for a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS environment.

Currently by running `apt update`  & `apt upgrade`, no new OpenSSL versions are installed by the system.

Comment: Hello. Ubuntu 22.04 already uses OpenSSL 3.0.2, and the latest vulnerabilities are patched.

Comment: When running `openssl version` I get `OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020`

Comment: My bad, the environment is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - I've just updated the initial post.

Comment: In this case, stay on version 1.1.1. It's still patched.

Comment: In my case:
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)

what then to do if two packages are blocked:

gjs libgjs0g

Comment: Exactly which CVE are you concerned about? Did you check the [Ubuntu CVE Tracker](https://ubuntu.com/security/cves) to see which version of OpenSSL 1.1.1 is appropriate, safe, and already-patched for you? 'Cause there is one.....